# How to store object pointers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

I'm fairly new to c++ and this problem's got me bad.
In my project I'm using SFML libraries to create asteroids. I declared a class named `_asteroids` and want to create a bunch of asteroid objects inside the class. Someone suggested I stored the objects inside an array. Later I learned that it wasn't possible to store objects inside an array, but you could store pointers to objects.

In summary I want to:

-Create objects inside the `_asteroids` class

-Store the pointers to those objects inside an array

-Be able to call those objects by their pointers from the array and change their values

How do I go about doing that? Here is some of my code to do with this:

```
class _asteroids{
    float angle; //Angle
    sf::Vector2f a_pos; //Position
    sf::Vector2f a_vel; //Velocity
    void makeAsteroids(int); //This generates the asteroid's appearance
    bool Remove(); //If this is false the object is removed

    public:
    void Update(); //This updates the position
};
```

Comment: To answer the question in the title, just like a normal array? What have you tried? What problems do you have with your attempt? Also, if you want to add and remove objects from the "array" at run-rime then consider [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Which part is the issue: creating objects, getting pointers to them, or putting things in an array?

Comment: I've tried to use arrays like so: 
foo[] = new _asteroids

Comment: The declaration `int foo[]` declares an *empty* array of *`int`*. C-style arrays needs to have a fixed size at time of compilation, and of course be an array of the objects you want in the array, e.g. `_asteroids foo[64]`.

Comment: @user2840146 It does not make sense having `asteroids`, but not `asteroid`.

Comment: i've read around about `std::vector`, I'll look into it.
Also, Scott, creating objects is not the issue but rather making pointers to them and storing those pointers in the array is.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't store objects inside an array"?  Specifically what do you mean by "object" (because the C++ standard says that `int foo[5];` is an object which is an array containing five objects, each of which is an int ... but you probably don't have that meaning of "object" in mind.

Comment: I don't mean object in that sense, but as a member of a class. In this case,  everytime I declare `_asteroids asteroid1` the `asteorid1` is what I mean by object. When I tried to put it inside an array like: `foo[1] = asteroid1` I receive and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you should - if at all possible/reasonable - avoid (raw) pointers and C-style arrays. C++ provides standard containers. Like C-style arrays they can hold all kind of element types but they have some benefits that a C-style array doesn't. For instance most containers can grow/shrink when you need it - in other words, their size can adjust itself as you add or remove elements. On top of that, they have a number of member function that will allow you to operate on the contained elements in an easy way.

The `vector` container is very popular. In many aspects it is just like an array once the elements have been added, i.e. you access elements using `var[i]`. You can add elements to the end of the vector using `push_back`.

Example:

```
std::vector<_asteroids> allAsteroids;

allAsteroids.push_back(_asteroids()); // Add _asteroids object to end of vector
allAsteroids.push_back(_asteroids()); // Add _asteroids object to end of vector
allAsteroids.push_back(_asteroids()); // Add _asteroids object to end of vector

cout << allAsteroids.size() << endl;  // Will print 3

for (auto& a : allAsteroids)  // Iterate over all asteroids in the vector
{
    a.Update();  // Call Update for current element
}

// The same as above in a different way
for (int i = 0; i < allAsteroids.size(); i++)
{
    allAsteroids[i].Update();  // Call Update for i'th element
}
```

This was just a few examples of what you can do with `vector`. There are many more.

Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ for more information - all member function of `vector` is shown to the left on that site.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can save Asteroid within an std::vector

```
class Asteroid {};

std::vector<Asteroid> asteroids;

Asteroid as1;
asteroids.push_back(as1);
```

Comment: what does the `asteroids.push_back` do?

Comment: Thanks, it worked nicely: placing all the class objects inside the vector allows me to destroy and keep track of them just the way I wanted to.